# Uri.AbsoluteUri is different than requested URL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, uri, asp.net-web-api2, url-encoding

I use HttpUtility.EncodeUrl to encode a querystring param. When I send request to the server then on the server side Uri.AbsoluteUri contains---in some cases---different querystring param values.

E.g. the to-be-escaped data string is

```
string data = "+-/*.,?!~\"£$%^&*()_{}[]@'#<>\\|`¬;:=";
```

HttpUtility.EncodeUrl(data) result is

```
%2b-%2f*.%2c%3f!%7e%22%c2%a3%24%25%5e%26*()_%7b%7d%5b%5d%40%27%23%3c%3e%5c%7c%60%c2%ac%3b%3a%3d
```

but when the request arrives on the server, HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri contains different string:

```
%2b-%2f*.%2c%3f!~%22%c2%a3%24%25%5e%26*()_%7b%7d[]%40'%23%3c%3e%5c%7c%60%c2%ac%3b:%3d
```

I need to compare them for HMAC auth mechanism, so I fixed this with function

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets escaped request URL string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetEscapedRequestUrl(Uri uri)
    {
        /**
         * When client uses HttpUtility.UrlEncode() some chars in Uri.AbsoluteUri on server side are NOT url-endcoded.
         * E.g. +-/*.,?!~"£$%^&*()_{}[]@'#<>\|`¬;:=
         * client-side: %2b-%2f*.%2c%3f!%7e%22%c2%a3%24%25%5e%26*()_%7b%7d%5b%5d%40%27%23%3c%3e%5c%7c%60%c2%ac%3b%3a%3d
         * server-side: %2b-%2f*.%2c%3f!~  %22%C2%A3%24%25%5E%26*()_%7B%7D[  ]  %40'  %23%3C%3E%5c%7C%60%C2%AC%3b:  %3d     //note: spaces are added to show the difference
         */
        string ret = string.Empty;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(uri.Scheme);
        sb.Append("://");
        sb.Append(uri.Authority);
        sb.Append(uri.LocalPath);
        sb.Append(uri.Query
            .Replace("~", "%7e")
            .Replace("[", "%5b")
            .Replace("]", "%5d")
            .Replace("'", "%27")
            .Replace(":", "%3a")
        );

        ret = sb.ToString();

        return ret;
    }
```

Can someone tell me, what causes the difference and if there is a better way to handle it, please, share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the type of the parameter from `Uri` to `string` in your *Action* will solve the problem.

A little experiment:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    string data = "+-/*.,?!~\"£$%^&*()_{}[]@'#<>\\|`¬;:=";

    return RedirectToAction("GetEncodedParam", new { data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data) });
}

public ActionResult GetEncodedParam(string data)
{
    var s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data); // here it's original string "+-/*.,?!~\"£$%^&*()_{}[]@'#<>\\|`¬;:="

    return new ContentResult { Content = s };
}
```